# How do I get Maven war plugin copying full jar in /lib of my web application?

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I have a web-app configured with a pom.xml.
This web-app relies on another maven module that produce a jar file. When i check the produced jar file size it is 8Ko. When i check this same jar file in my /lib web application, it is 5Ko.

A bunch of classes are simply ignored when the jar file reaches my /lib directory,
causing ClassNotFoundException when runing the web application.

Why is my jar trimmed ?

**Web-app pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>record</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
<artifactId>record-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>record-webapp</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JSF 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3-b02</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3-b02</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Internal dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
        <artifactId>record-dao</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>record</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverName>web</serverName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**record-dao pom.xml**

```
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>record</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
<artifactId>record-dao</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>record-dao</name>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.3-606.jdbc4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Internal dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.record</groupId>
        <artifactId>record-commun</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You will have to show some config if you want useful help. Post relevant bits of both pom files, please

Comment: I have added the pom.xml files of the webapp and its module

Comment: @Jarod prime-repo don't have com.company directory; only com/prime

Comment: and which goal you are running ?

Comment: dependent jar : mvn clean install /
web app : mvn clean package jboss:hard-deploy

Comment: can you cleanup local repo once and try once `clean install` , its wierd

Comment: i have cleaned up local repo and try `clean install`. In local repo, jar file is 8Ko but in war file, jar file is still 5Ko!

Comment: @stephan - please don't keep asking the same question again and again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution. In the web-app/web-inf/lib directory, there was a jar file who was sharing the same name with the dependent jar file.

For a reason I don't understand, maven-war-plugin used to take this old jar file rather than the freshly one I installed in my local repository.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like perhaps you are looking at different versions of the jar file.

Are you doing a `mvn install` of the dependent jar before building the webapp project?

Comment: `mvn install` on dependent module => 8Ko in the target folder and 8Ko in my local repository. In /lib => 5Ko :(

Comment: and it's the same version number? do you have plugins in the webapp that modify the dependencies?

Comment: The version for dependent jar is 1.0.0, the same in pom.xml. I have no plugin that modify the dependencies

Comment: what if you wipe the jar artifact from your local repo and re-install?

Comment: i have deleted manually the jar and `mvn clean install` in the jar file dir. After recompiling, the webapp, the jar still gets trimmed :\

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if it has to do with your dependent jar not being snap shot

Just to prove this point can you go to the local maven repository (not the target directory) on your build machine and delete the current yourdepend-1.0.0.jar file and run mvn install again, I think that should solve your problem (If it is the snap shot issue)

Comment: No luck :( I still get the trimmed jar

Answer (score 1):

Did you run maven clean package or maven clean install before compiling the war. If you have done package only then the local jar will not be bundled in the war instead the jar in the local repository will be used (which may be old).

the war plugin presumes that web-inf/lib directory jars, don't put any jars there in the lib, manage them through dependency, and change scope accordingly.

Comment: I have deleted manually the jar file from my local repository. mvn clean install it. mvn clean package my web app, and i still get a trimmed version of the package not the full one in my local repository :(

Comment: then it sounds like you are using a repository snapshot(like ABC-SNAPSHOT.jar), check your settings.xml and check it in your repository and compare the size.